# Database choice for a dictionary

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I want to create a semantic texts analyzer. To do that I need to store a lot of words roots in the database - the basic language vocabulary which is about one hundred thousand words. 
Is there any pattern or common architecture and what kind of database should I use - relational or nosql(probably mongodb)?

There are 26 letters and many thousand of words can start from each. If using relational db should I create 26 different tables for each letter or if using nosql should I store them all together?

Comment: why don't you simply create one or 26 text files, that you load once. This looks like you have to load the whole data set in memory, doesn't you ?

Comment: I don't this so you need a DB. I'd go with a datastructure that will fit the requirements e.g. Trie http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Steve, lukas, I don't think that's a good idea to store the data not in a database. I need a basis lexis for different time periods(different centuries) to try to identify the time the text was written.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SPARQL loaded with WORDNET is a good start.